# Is the Death Star Lego Model in Spider-Man: Homecoming a real product?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, star-wars, props, spider-man-homecoming

Is the Death Star made of Lego, in *Spider-Man: Homecoming* real product? Or was it created as props only?

[image]

Comment: Crossover question, also relevant on [Lego Stack Exchange](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are actually *several* variations of the Death Star set.

The one in the movie was around 3800 pieces, so I believe it was intended to be [Set 10188](https://brickset.com/sets/10188-1/Death-Star).

That modeled was retired a couple years ago and replaced with one that is mostly the same, but has different minifigures and same other minor changes. [This review](https://brickset.com/article/23454/review-75159-death-star) details the differences. This is the set currently visible on LEGO Shop at Home and available  at other retailers.

Something worth pointing out though, at least in my opinion, is that there's inconsistenty with the displayed set.

This is the Emperor we actually see on screen:

[image]

But that's from the newer 4000+ piece set. The 3800 hundred piece set has the greyish skinned Emperor instead of the tan one we saw:

[image]

So, there's some inconsistency there. They probably sourced the new set but someone wrote the old set's count into the script. Or, the MCU LEGO set is not the same as reality's.

Comment: I heard/read that they had 7 prop set for the scene and 7th one made into actual film, maybe they messed up a bit there

Comment: @AnkitSharma Unfortunately the only thing that really stood out to me was Palpatine and the piece count number. Once the movie comes out, I might actually be able to use a screenshot to determine which _instruction_ booklet they used (by comparing the visible instructions and page # to the instructions for the two different sets). Not sure I could eyeball which finished set is which, though, as I've only seen each in person once and would have to guess based on images/video reviews.

Comment: I owned this set, it's awesome - gave it away, that was awesome as the recipients loved it, was just something fun to build over Xmas one year!

Comment: As the linked review mentions: there's an obvious change to the turbolaser on the garbage compactor level between set 10188 and 75159. It's probably obvious enough in a movie still. Except that the still in the question shows the other face of the model. If the movie shows the box, it's visible in the box artwork. I have 10188.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe No box in the movie, and the instructions are only shown while opened flat, so no cover.

Answer (score 24):

There is indeed a LEGO Death Star available in the official [LEGO Shop](https://shop.lego.com/en-NL/Death-Star-75159). I'm not sure if it's the same one as in the movie, though (but it seems so).

[image]

<sub>(source: official LEGO website)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, The only thing is that I remember a different count of pieces from the movie (3800/3900~) I might be wrong. And this one is 4016.

Comment: now if I only had those 499 euros....

Comment: hmm.... "not to scale"

Comment: @Michael I think if it was to mini figure scale it would be about the size of Manhatten.

Comment: @SGR A lego minifig is about 1/44th the size of an adult human (4 cm versus 176 cm). The Death Star is 160 km high. The Death Star on Minifig scale would be 3.64 km high, or roughly the width of Manhattan. Wired has written an article on a minifig sized death star: https://www.wired.com/2012/02/could-you-build-a-scale-lego-model-of-the-death-star/

Comment: I was at Lego Land in San Diego for the 2005 Star Wars weekend, and someone had made the hangar w/ the Millenium Falcon in it ... I've found pictures of ones online, but his was *huge* and had dioramas around the sides -- Chewbacca being led by storm troopers in chains, the place that Luke swung across, Obi-Wan shutting off the tractor beam, etc.  It was easily 4' x 6'.  Not sure of the full height, as the lift in the hangar bay went into the table, but at least 2' tall.

Comment: This looks like the same one, but in the movie his friend says the kit had 3,000 pieces. I don't think you could fit it on your lap if it was 3,000 pieces.

Comment: @Reactgular Oh, you definitely could. Don't underestimate how high a number the pieces in a set can amass to. You can easily reach that with a set of this spatial volume. It might weight about 3 kg, but that's not too much for a lap either.